# saved image file showing twice when I refresh combobox list

Tags: database, vb.net, combobox, blob

So I am working with blobs in visual basic, and I'm saving image files to a database.  When I save them I have their name.jpg showing up in a combobox, but when I save another image and it refreshes the list, the name of the previous image shows twice.  I'm not sure how I managed that.  I am new to this so don't look down on me too much!

When the button on my form is clicked:

```
Private Sub btnSaveBlob_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveBlob.Click
    SaveBlobToDatabase()
    refreshBlobList()
End Sub
```

My methods:

```
Private Sub SaveBlobToDatabase()

    GetCompleteFilePath()

    Dim BLOB() As Byte

    Dim FileStream As New IO.FileStream _
    (CompleteFilePath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)

    Dim reader As New IO.BinaryReader(FileStream)

    BLOB = reader.ReadBytes(CInt(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(CompleteFilePath).Length))
    FileStream.Close()
    reader.Close()

    Dim SaveDocCommand As New SqlCommand
    SaveDocCommand.Connection = conn
    SaveDocCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DocumentStorage" &
    "(FileName, DocumentFile)" &
    "VALUES (@FileName, @DocumentFile)"

    Dim FileNameParameter As New SqlParameter("@FileName", SqlDbType.NChar)
    Dim DocumentFileParameter As New SqlParameter("@DocumentFile", SqlDbType.Binary)
    SaveDocCommand.Parameters.Add(FileNameParameter)
    SaveDocCommand.Parameters.Add(DocumentFileParameter)

    FileNameParameter.Value =
    CompleteFilePath.Substring(CompleteFilePath.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)

    DocumentFileParameter.Value = BLOB

    Try
        SaveDocCommand.Connection.Open()
        SaveDocCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show(FileNameParameter.Value.ToString &
        "saved to database.", "BLOB Saved!", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Save Failed",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        SaveDocCommand.Connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub refreshBlobList()
        Dim GetBlobListCommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT FileName FROM DocumentStorage", conn)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        GetBlobListCommand.Connection.Open()
        reader = GetBlobListCommand.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            lstBlob.Items.Add(reader(0))
        End While
        reader.Close()
        GetBlobListCommand.Connection.Close()
        If lstBlob.Items.Count > 0 Then
            lstBlob.SelectedIndex = 0
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Clear `lstBlob` before reading back the list of files (in `refreshBlobList()`).

Comment: ugh thanks, I realized I needed to clear it right after I posted, good to know I did the right thing though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in .net that show you a .Dispose method should be disposed. They have unmanaged code and need to properly release things. Connections, Commands, Streams, and Readers fall into this group. Luckily .net has provided Using...End Using blocks that handle this for us even if there is an error. For this reason, these objects should be kept local to the methods where they are used.

As much as possible, methods should perform a single task. I pulled out the code to create the byte array to a separate Function. I also split the data access code from the user interace code. You may want to put the data access code in a separate class. This would come in handy if you want to change to a web app, for example.

In the data access code:

You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Likewise, pass the CommandText and Connection directly to the constructor of the command. The .Add method of the .Parameters collection will create a new parameter from the name and datatype passed to it. You can also set the value on the same line.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim RowsAdded As Integer
    Try
        RowsAdded = SaveBlobToDatabase()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Save Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    If RowsAdded = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Saved to database.", "BLOB Saved!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function SaveBlobToDatabase() As Integer
    Dim RowsAdded As Integer
    Dim CompleteFilePath As String = GetCompleteFilePath()
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            SaveCommand As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DocumentStorage(FileName, DocumentFile) VALUES(@FileName, @DocumentFile);", conn)
        SaveCommand.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Path.GetFileName(CompleteFilePath) 'Requires Imports System.IO
        SaveCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentFile", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = GetByteArrayFromFile(CompleteFilePath)
        conn.Open()
        RowsAdded = SaveCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Return RowsAdded
End Function

Private Function GetByteArrayFromFile(FullPath As String) As Byte()
    Dim Blob() As Byte
    Using FileStream As New IO.FileStream(FullPath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read),
            reader As New IO.BinaryReader(FileStream)
        Blob = reader.ReadBytes(CInt(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(FullPath).Length))
    End Using
    Return Blob
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    lstBlob.Items.Clear()
    lstBlob.DataSource = refreshBlobList()
    lstBlob.DisplayMember = "FileName"
    If lstBlob.Items.Count > 0 Then
        lstBlob.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Function refreshBlobList() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
        GetBlobListCommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT FileName FROM DocumentStorage", conn)
        conn.Open()
        dt.Load(GetBlobListCommand.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```